# Manifolds, questions about gluing

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In Tu's [An Introduction to Manifolds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441973990), he mentions: "*If $U$ is an open subset of a manifold $M$, then the inclusion $i:U\to M$ is both an immersion and a submersion.*"

> Is the statement true because $\dim TU = \dim TM$ and by dimensionality argument $di_p$ is both injective and surjective?
>
> Is the inclusion, $i$,  also an embedding?
>
> Is the inclusion $i$ ever stated or used explicitly in calculations? For example, a chart on a manifold $M$ is $\phi : U\subset M \to \mathbb{R}^n$
>   so if $\Phi : M \to \mathbb{R}^n$, the inclusion is used to restrict $\Phi$ from a global chart to a local chart $\phi = \Phi \circ i$.
>
> Assuming that $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$, and $U,V$ open sets that cover $M$, is the inclusion $j_U : U\cap V \to U$ an immersion, submersion, or embedding? Is $j_U$ ever used explicitly in calculations?
>
> What does [Hirsch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387901485) mean by saying that "*...a manifold is built from elementary objects (open sets) "glued" together by maps of specified kind (diffeomorphisms)..*"

Answer (score 1):

Wlog we can suppose that $U$ is the domain of a chart: $\varphi: U\longrightarrow U'\subset\Bbb R^n$ and:
$$\varphi\circ i\circ\varphi^{-1}: U'\longrightarrow U'$$
is the identity in a open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, so $i$ is local diffeomorphism $\implies$ for all $p\in U$ $di_p$ is bijective (injective and surjective) $\implies$ $i$ is immersion and submersion.

Also $i$ is an embedding = injective immersion which is homeomorphism onto its image. And by the same reasons $j_U$ is an immersion/submersion/embedding.

> "...a manifold is built from elementary objects (open sets) "glued" together by maps of specified kind (diffeomorphisms).."

means that a manifold can be considered a quotient. Example: consider $S^1 = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,\vert\,x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$. $S^1\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ and $S^1\setminus\{(0,-1)\}$ are homeomorphic to intervals. Take the disjoint union of both intervals and identify points with the same image in $S^1$.